Title Supression in SAS ODS HTML Output
Basic SAS ODS title question - I'd like to have an overall document title for an ODS output. However, it always duplicates itself or suppresses the succeeding titles in the output. What is the proper way to note an overall document title without affecting the succeeding titles? None of the common suggestions accomplish this, such as: clearing the document title, adding 'nogtitle', 'bodytitle', ensuring succeeding title numbers, etc. One of many combinations I've tried is presented below - in this example the overall title appears multiple times - once above title 2 and then above title 3:
Title "Report of Monthly Sales";

title2 "Print of First Ten Observations of East Regional Sales";
Proc print data = eastregion (obs=10);
run;
title2;

title3 "Freq of East Regional Sales";
Proc freq data = eastregion;
tables region;
run;
title3;
 


You want to remove title2 and title3 without the ;?  Use this command: sed -i '3d;8d' your_file  Add ;#d to delete additional lines.

In your code the title2; statement clears the sub-title, but the original title statement is still in effect.
You would have to use title; to clear the main title after your first output and set a subtitle for each subsequent output step.
title "Report of Monthly Sales"; * create the main title;

title2 "Print of First Ten Observations of East Regional Sales"; * create the sub-title;
Proc print data = eastregion (obs=10);
run;
title; * clear the main title;

title2 "Freq of East Regional Sales"; * change the sub-title;
Proc freq data = eastregion;
tables region;
run;
title2;


Thank you, but whenever I have used that approach, the main title does not appear in the output - gets suppressed.
